# Not able to add Omnigroup framework for rtf editor in a my iPad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I have been trying to add omnigroup framework for editing rtf files into my local iPad application. But always I am getting the errors like OmniBase/OmniBase.h, OmniFoundation/OmniFoundation.h files are not found.

I tried with different combinations of settings in the build settings of project target. But  did not work. I am using Xcode version 4.2.1,
Mac OS X : 10.7 and IOS 5 Lion OS.

Comment: Please provide a link for the framework which you are using

Comment: @ Mrunal, you can clone the omnigroup framework with sample text editor project by using following link:
https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup.git

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a lot of Xcode configuration involved in using the Omni frameworks. I recently went through the learning process myself and wrote a [lengthy tutorial](http://sandmoose.com/post/53903897669/how-to-use-ouieditableframe-with-the-omnigroup). My tutorial is centered around using `OUIEditableFrame` but it should be a good starting point for whatever part of the framework you're looking to use.

In a nutshell:

1. Make sure you're including Omni's `Configuration` directory in your project.
2. Add the required frameworks by adding the appropriate `.xcodeproj` files from Omni to your project. Many frameworks are dependent on other so all dependencies will need to be added.
3. Add required libraries to the **Link Binary with Libraries** section of the **Build Phases** tab.
4. Add required libraries to the **Target Dependencies** section of the **Build Phases** tab.
5. Edit your Schema. Select **Build** and add the required libraries.